# Where to check logs of webserver_config.py in Airflow?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, airflow

```
  import os
  import logging
  from flask.appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
  from airflow.www.security import AirflowSecurityManager
  
  AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
  AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True
  AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
  
  log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  log.setLevel(os.getenv("AIRFLOW__LOGGING__FAB_LOGGING_LEVEL", "INFO"))
  
  OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
      {
          "name": "egast",
          "icon": "fa-address-card",
          "token_key": "access_token",
          "remote_app": {
              "client_id": "<id>",
              "client_secret": "<secret>",
              "client_kwargs": {
                  "scope": "<scope>",
                  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
              },
              "access_token_method": "POST",
              "access_token_params": {
                  "client_id": "<id>",
              },
              "request_token_url": None,
              "api_base_url": "<url>",
              "access_token_url": "<url>/token.oauth2",
              "authorize_url": "<url>/authorization.oauth2"
          }
      }
  ]
  
  class CustomSecurityManager(AirflowSecurityManager):
  
      def oauth_user_info(sm, provider, response=None):
          if provider == "egast":
              me = sm.oauth_remote[provider].get("userinfo")
              log.debug(me.data)
              logging.info(me.data)
              logging.debug(me.data)
              print(me.data)
          else:
              log.debug("Nothing!!")
              logging.info("Nothing!!")
              logging.debug("Nothing!!")
              print("Nothing!!")
  
  
  SECURITY_MANAGER_CLASS = CustomSecurityManager
  AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {
      "FAB_USERS": ['User'],
      "FAB_ADMINS": ['Admin']
  }
```

I'm trying to integrate oauth in Airflow and I have a class CustomSecurityManager where I'm printing or logging few statements to debub. There are couple of log files generated under /home/airflow/airflow/ like airflow.cfg, webserver.log, webserver.out, scheduler.log, etc. But none of them contains these webserver_config.py logs. **So, where exactly can I find those logs after starting Airflow webserver & scheduler?**

Answer (score 1):

Could you add the following:

```
  import logging
  from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import RedirectStdHandler
  
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  handler = RedirectStdHandler(stream='stdout')
  logger.addHandler(handler)
  logger.info("hello-world")
```

The log formatting is off compared to the other log statements, but I get the following now:

```
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2022-08-17 12:40:22,554] {webserver_config.py:16} INFO - hello-world
```

Logs for the webserver are written to stdout by default, so in kubernetes they are obtainable via the `kubectl logs` command

(I'm using the Kubernetes executor setup, but I don't expect this will matter, just go to wherever stdout lives in your setup)